# UsbDeviceConnection.BulkTransfer doesn't work in Android API > 23

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, serial-port

I realized a mobile application to communicate with a NFC captor (CR95HF). It works perfectly in Android with API < 23 (before Android Marshmallow 6.0), but it doesn't works with Android with API >= 23.
I identified the problem and the problem is in BulkTransfer function, because it returns -1 (no response). I checked and try to change the different parameters, but nothing changes :
- direction of the endpoint is correct
- length to store : ok
- length field : ok
- Timeout parameter : I put 1000 ms and try to change with other values, but no effect
I tried to change the endpoints too.

```
public void ioWrite(UsbDeviceConnection mConnection, UsbEndpoint mBulkOutEndpoint, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (mConnection == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Connection was closed.");
        }

        int result = mConnection.BulkTransfer(mBulkOutEndpoint, buffer, offset, count, TIMEOUT);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Bulk transfer failed.");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for you.

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, no I never found the solution unfortunately.